# Google Webmasters structured data errors

Tags: google, google-search-console

I recently updated a wordpress blog to my own domain and have been moving everything over and coming to grips with making the site look half decent.

When I run the domain through Google's Webmaster structured data, I get multiple errors. in fact, an error for every single item!!! Every error seems to have the same problem- **missing Author** and **missing Updated.** And mentions something to do with Hentry? I googled that to try and figure it out,but it pretty much made my head explode!!

FYI I know nothing about CSS etc.And I know I'm a bit over my head with it all, but I think it's too late to turn back to the regular wordpress account now. ugh.

So, are these errors important? and... how do I fix them?!

Answer (score 1):

You can read about structured data here: http://schema.org/ and Google's particular implementation here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data

In short, you need to decide whether the content you're providing will benefit from having rich snippets available in search results (an example of this is searching for "SomeStore hours" and seeing the actual hours in a readable grid right on the search results page).

If you're just running a personal blog, this may not matter to you.

If you're running an e-commerce business, this can be extremely valuable both for assisting customers in finding your products, and assisting Google in displaying accurate results and ranking.

Answer (score -1):

It's because of your theme you are using for your websites.

These errors often come in pairs, or in quartets! Here’s a list of the usual suspects:

```
Error: At least one field must be set for HatomEntry.
Error: Missing required field “entry-title”.
Error: Missing required field “updated”.
Error: Missing required hCard “author”.
Error: Missing "name"
```

You have to change your post or article `div` with some extra `div` to include name of author.

```
<div class="post-info">
<span class="date published time" title="2013-10-14T21:54:14+00:00">Date</span>
By
<span class="author vcard"><span class="fn">Author Name</span></span> <br />
Last updated on
<span class="updated">Date</span>
</div>
```

Date published, updated are other fields which you'll have to add.

Source: [How to fix Structured Data errors in Google Webmasters – WordPress](http://dothisbest.com/how-to/fix-structured-data-errors-in-google-webmasters)

Comment: Please add a disclosure for links to your own site or blog.